# Display FORMATTED XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I am retrieving an XML document from a web service (UPS actually), and I can pull the information I need from the XML, but I can't get the XML to display in the XML format. I can get it to display in a label and literal, but its all ran together. The nodes aren't displaying. The nodes display in a text box control, but it still runs together (no brks)

Any idea how to take the XML document that i get from the service and display it just like it would if you open up an XML doc in IE?

Thanks

BTW... i have search all day for this and the only thing i could find is if i was displaying a static file, which i'm not. I also tried doing the stringbuilder/stringwriter, but no luck. I'm still pretty new at this stuff so i could be missing something.

HELP... PLEASE!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the code you have tried so far.  Are you employing `Server.HtmlEncode()` in your algorithm?

Comment: @pseudocoder, no i'm not doing `Server.HTMLEncode` (i'm not really sure what that is). As I mentioned, I have tried stringbuilder/stringwriter and <pre>. I don't have code for it except when i tried the <pre> which you can find here, http://screencast.com/t/DDFAcqHjlG & here, http://screencast.com/t/L4zcuV0F7 . I don't have the other code because i have tried so many things. So if you have any suggestions on how to try these ways, or others, i'm all ears! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try encompassing the XML in the

```
<pre>... your xml</pre>
```

tags.

Comment: tried it... doesn't work, at least the way i'm doing it.

http://screencast.com/t/DDFAcqHjlG - showing the XML (with the "pre" being passed), but my XML is just all ran together. 

http://screencast.com/t/L4zcuV0F7

Comment: It looks like it's registering the XML as a literal.  This may be a long shot but try using Javascript to pull the XML out of the pre tag and re-insert it (with a new pre tag surrounding it) onto the page.  For instance:
$("body").append("<pre>"+$(".litXMLResponseClassName pre").html()+"</pre>");

Comment: Actually I put the XML in the litteral because I wasn't sure how else to pass it with the <pre> tag. If there is something else i can load it in there I will it! 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can try loading it in an iFrame =)

Comment: The issue there is saving the XML then setting the iFrame source to that file, all dynamically. I guess that might be an option, but 1 would think that if I had and xmldocument object, i could display it fairly easily in its format. I guess not.........?

Comment: It's been a while since I've been in the same situation.  But yes, you would think =]